# How to don't let the element brake if it's not the children

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make both `.quote-container` and `#new-quote` elements in the same line even if the window width is very small. For example 83pixels. Using `min-width` on the `.quote-container` element worked, however, using the same technique on the `#new-quote` element didn't work.

Maybe that's because `#new-quote` isn't the children of `.quote-container`? I even tried to make it a child and it was even worse (picture was taken on the desktop window size):
[image]

What I'd like to achieve in visual:
[image]

```js
var getNewQuote = function(callback) {
  var quote = {};

  quote.text = 'Example';
  quote.author = 'Example';
  $(".loading").hide();
  callback(quote);

};
var quoteContainerStartingPadding,
  quoteContainerEndingPadding,
  newQuoteEndingPadding;
if ($(window).width() > 648) {
  quoteContainerStartingPadding = "0 2.5rem";
  quoteContainerEndingPadding = "2.5rem";
  newQuoteEndingPadding = "2.5rem .75rem";
} else {
  quoteContainerStartingPadding = "0 1.5em";
  quoteContainerEndingPadding = "1.5rem";
  newQuoteEndingPadding = "1.5rem .75rem";
}

$(".quote-container").css("padding", quoteContainerStartingPadding);
getNewQuote(function(quote) {
    var getRandomColor = function() {
      var colors = ["#ff9966", "#7f00ff", "#396afc", "#0cebeb", "#06beb6", "#642b73", "#36d1dc", "#cb356b", "#3a1c71", "#ef3b36", "#159957", "#000046", "#007991", "#56ccf2", "#f2994a", "#e44d26", "#4ac29a", "#f7971e", "#34e89e", "#6190e8", "#3494e6", "#ee0979"],
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
      return colors[randomNumber];
    };
    var updateText = function($t) {
      var twitter = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=";
      twitter += '"' + quote.text + '" ';
      twitter += quote.author;
      var tumblr = "https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool?posttype=quote&tags=quotes,freecodecamp&caption=";
      tumblr += quote.author;
      tumblr += "&content=";
      tumblr += quote.text;
      tumblr += "&canonicalUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tumblr.com%2Fbuttons&shareSource=tumblr_share_button";
      var $icon = $("<i class='fa fa-quote-left'>").prop("aria-hidden", true);
      $t.find(".quote-text").html("").append($icon, quote.text);
      $t.find(".quote-author").html("- " + quote.author);
      $("#tweet-quote").attr("href", twitter);
      $("#tumblr-quote").attr("href", tumblr);
    };
    var calcNewHeight = function(q) {
      var $temp = $("<div>", {
        class: "quote-container temp",
      }).appendTo($("body"));
      $temp.append($("<div>", {
        class: "quote-text"
      }), $("<div>", {
        class: "quote-author"
      }));
      updateText($temp, q);
      var h = $temp.height() + 40;
      $temp.remove();
      return h;
    };
    var changeColor = function(newColor) {
      $("body, .button:not(#new-quote)").animate({
        backgroundColor: newColor
      });
      $("#new-quote").animate({
        color: newColor
      });
      $(".quote-text, .quote-author").css("color", newColor);
      if ($("#modStyle").length === 0) {
        $("head").append("<style id='modStyle'>#new-quote:before {background:" + newColor + ";} .lds-eclipse {box-shadow: 0 .25rem 0 0 " + newColor + ";}</style>");
      } else {
        $("head style#modStyle").html("#new-quote:before {background:" + newColor + ";} .lds-eclipse {box-shadow: 0 .25rem 0 0 " + newColor + ";}");
      }
    };
    var getQuote = function() {
      var nc, nh = 0;
      nc = getRandomColor();
      nh = calcNewHeight(quote);
      changeColor(nc);
      $(".quote-container, #new-quote").animate({
        height: nh / 16 + "rem",
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });
      $(".quote-container").animate({
        padding: quoteContainerEndingPadding
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });
      $("#new-quote").animate({
        padding: newQuoteEndingPadding
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });
      updateText($(".quote-container"), quote);
      $(".quote-container").children().not($(".loading")).fadeTo(750, 1);
    };
    $(".quote-container, #new-quote").css({
      visibility: "visible",
      height: 0
    });
    $("#new-quote").css("padding", "0 .75rem");
    getQuote();
  }

);
var two = function() {
  $(".quote-container").children().not($(".loading")).hide();
  $(".loading").show();
  getNewQuote(function(quote) {
    var getRandomColor = function() {
      var colors = ["#ff9966", "#7f00ff", "#396afc", "#0cebeb", "#06beb6", "#642b73", "#36d1dc", "#cb356b", "#3a1c71", "#ef3b36", "#159957", "#000046", "#007991", "#56ccf2", "#f2994a", "#e44d26", "#4ac29a", "#f7971e", "#34e89e", "#6190e8", "#3494e6", "#ee0979"],
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
      return colors[randomNumber];
    };
    var updateText = function($t) {
      var twitter = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=";
      twitter += '"' + quote.text + '" ';
      twitter += quote.author;
      var tumblr = "https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool?posttype=quote&tags=quotes,freecodecamp&caption=";
      tumblr += quote.author;
      tumblr += "&content=";
      tumblr += quote.text;
      tumblr += "&canonicalUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tumblr.com%2Fbuttons&shareSource=tumblr_share_button";
      var $icon = $("<i class='fa fa-quote-left'>").prop("aria-hidden", true);
      $t.find(".quote-text").html("").append($icon, quote.text);
      $t.find(".quote-author").html("- " + quote.author);
      $("#tweet-quote").attr("href", twitter);
      $("#tumblr-quote").attr("href", tumblr);
    };
    var calcNewHeight = function(q) {
      var $temp = $("<div>", {
        class: "quote-container temp",
      }).appendTo($("body"));
      $temp.append($("<div>", {
        class: "quote-text"
      }), $("<div>", {
        class: "quote-author"
      }));
      updateText($temp, q);
      var h = $temp.height() + 40;
      $temp.remove();
      return h;
    };
    var changeColor = function(newColor) {
      $("body, .button:not(#new-quote)").animate({
        backgroundColor: newColor
      });
      $("#new-quote").animate({
        color: newColor
      });
      $(".quote-text, .quote-author").css("color", newColor);
      if ($("#modStyle").length === 0) {
        $("head").append("<style id='modStyle'>#new-quote:before {background:" + newColor + ";} .lds-eclipse {box-shadow: 0 .25rem 0 0 " + newColor + ";}</style>");
      } else {
        $("head style#modStyle").html("#new-quote:before {background:" + newColor + ";} .lds-eclipse {box-shadow: 0 .25rem 0 0 " + newColor + ";}");
      }
    };
    var getQuote = function() {
      var nc = getRandomColor(),
        nh = calcNewHeight(quote);
      $(".quote-container").children().not($(".loading")).css("opacity", 0);
      changeColor(nc);
      $(".quote-container, #new-quote").animate({
        height: nh / 16 + "rem",
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });
      updateText($(".quote-container"), quote);
      $(".quote-container").children().not($(".loading")).fadeTo(750, 1);
    };
    getQuote();
  });
}

;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.quote-container {
  width: 35%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 15rem;
}

.quote-text {
  font-size: 1.625rem;
}

.quote-text i {
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
}

.quote-text p {
  display: inline;
}

.quote-author {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0.4rem 2rem 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.button {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.button:not(#new-quote):hover {
  opacity: 0.8 !important;
}

.button:not(#new-quote) {
  min-width: 1rem;
  min-height: 1rem;
}

.button i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#new-quote {
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff !important;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 0.25625rem;
  color: #333;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#new-quote:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#new-quote:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.v-align {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

footer a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

footer a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


/* Loading animation */

@keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.lds-eclipse {
  -webkit-animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 62.5em) {
  .quote-container {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
  .quote-container {
    width: 65%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 17.96875em) {
  .quote-container {
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="v-align text-center">
  <div class="quote-container">
    <div class="quote-text">
    </div>
    <div class="quote-author"></div>
    <a id="tweet-quote" class="button"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a id="tumblr-quote" class="button"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
    <div class="loading">
      <div class="lds-eclipse"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="new-quote" class="button">New quote</div>
  <footer>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Kestis500">Created by LukasLSC</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**: Codepen: https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/KZvXgB?editors=0110

Comment: Can someone explain why downvote?

Comment: Because a good question has a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue, and this has way too much information.  (I didn't downvote, but I did vote to close).

Comment: Thank you, i'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align things in CSS you usually have two different positioning concepts you can use for this purpose:

1. display (flex)
2. float

Usually it is a good idea to put all elements you want to align in a wrapping container like a div. In this manner you can just focus on your aligning issue and forget about the general layout - means where you want to have your aligned elements in the layout eventually. You can later on just position the wrapper and do not have to worry about the elements inside.

Another best practice is to give all your elements that this container inherits from a dimension (at least width). A common mistake is that elements that should be aligned break just because the parent element does not have enough space to fit all elements on one line. If you want to know why I provide an example at the end, just follow the *.

But lets go back to the two concepts that you can use. Which one you should use depends on one hand what other attributes you need to give the respective elements and what browsers you need to support. If you only want to support newer browser versions you can go with flexbox, the more secure way to do this is use percentages for widths and float.

Flexbox

```
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row; // this makes your elements align horizontally
}

.child1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

The flex attribute determines the dimension of a child. So consider the parent as width: 100%; and the numbers you give as a first parameter to flex is the ratio of the child's dimension compared to the other children.

Float

```
.container {
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%; // this must be relative to the containers parent of course
}

.child1 {
   width: 75%;
   float: left;
}

.child2 {
   width: 25%;
   float: left;
}
```

Mind that float takes effect on the elements following in the document flow AFTER the element that you give the float attribute. Also take into account that you might need to calculate margins, paddings or borders in additionally to the elements' widths (except for paddings when using box-sizing: border-box) and that elements containing only floated elements lose their "automatic" dimensions as floated elements lose their information about height and width as well. (overflow: hidden on the container solves this issue for you)

*In a responsive design e.g. you should give the highest parent a width of 100%. If you provide to a child width: 50%; it will now have exactly 50% of the entire width. If you now give the child of the child width: 50% it will be 25% of the entire width. This is less error prone then giving the child's child directly 25%. Let's assume later on you give the child a width of 50% the width of the child's child (25%) will relate to the childs width instead of the parent. So you will end up with a width of 12.5% for the child's child relative to the entire width.

Comment: It's great you want to help, but I might point out that you can accomplish these things with other methods too: display table-cell.  Or display inline-block.  Or position absolute.  Floats are almost always my last resort.

Comment: Yes you can but you should avoid using position too often as it is a harsh manipulation of the document flow. table-cell and inline-block can be used as well but in my opinion it has too many side effects and is also meant to be used for other purposes as the names state themselves. If you just want to get things in a row floating or flexbox is the easiest way to go.

Comment: Nice answer, I'll try to implement it on my project.

Comment: I've done what you said and I don't know why, but it doesn't work. https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/KZvXgB?editors=1000. The "created by element" now is on the right side instead of in the bottom and when I resize the window it still breaks: http://prntscr.com/hvmpcz. It also broke the main `v-align` and `text-center` classes. I think i shouldn't use float here.

Comment: You need to clear the float after the container. So the "created by" needs to get a clear:both. This should fix it. What do you mean by v-align and text-center classes? How did it break it?